# Keep expanding content from pushing footer down

Tags: html, css

on the following page: http://www.mkleinwebdesign.com/optimarestore/faq/

When more than one question is toggled open/expanded it pushes the footer down. Is there a way to fix it so that the white content section expands at the top and doesn't push the footer content down?

HTML

```
div class="content left" style-"margin-right: 30px; min-height: 500px">
```

CSS

```
 .content {
    background: white;
    padding: 35px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #767676;
    line-height: 22px;
    }

.left {
    float: left;
    width: 57%;
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What about closing all questions and expand only the one clicked?

Comment: The footer doesn't get pushed down for me, the question just expands over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to clear your floats properly to keep content from escaping the container. The div with classes **content** and **left** is floated left, but the float is not cleared before the footer. This allows content which “escapes” the container div to push the footer content down.

The problem, visually explained: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

I noticed you already have CSS in place to make clearing floats possible with the use of a div with class **clearfix**.

`<div class="clearfix"></div>`

Just add this before your footer div, and it’ll fix this problem.

There are also other methods for clearing floats—some that even allow you to avoid adding such non-semantic HTML markup as empty divs, but it looks like that’s the method that’s already in use on this site, so I'd recommend sticking with what's already in place.

Comment: Worked perfectly and thank you for explaining the alternative options as well. In the future I will probably try to set up one of the other methods. Thanks again!